# Yii2 check to see if lazy loading has been done already

Tags: php, yii2, lazy-loading

So I'm wondering, I would like to see if a table has been lazy/eager loaded already, without actually loading it when I'm checking. For instance:

```
class Listing extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public function getListingImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ListingImage::className(), ['listing_id' => 'id'])->orderBy(['position' => SORT_ASC]);
    }


    public function getCoverImage()
    {
        if (isset($this->listingImages)) {
            return $this->listingImages[0];
        }

        // Find cover image
    }
}
```

So when I do `isset($this->listingImages)` it will always return `true` because if it's not already loaded it will go and load the images, but in this case, thats not what I want to do. The example is basic, but there's some extra filtering I want to do, so I would rather just do a custom select. How can I actually check to see if the eager/lazy loading has been done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [isRelationPopulated()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#isRelationPopulated()-detail) method of the ActiveRecord class.